# issue with permission in /system/bin files after updating the images built with security keys

Tags: android

I built the android with secuirity keys by taking the reference the below link:

```
http://www.kandroid.org/online-pdk/guide/release_keys.html
```

I got the signed-img.zip.
I updated the zip using  fatboot.
After rebooting I am getting errors in debug tool:

```
init: cannot execve('/system/bin/servicemanager'): Permission denied 
init: cannot execve('/system/bin/mediaserver'): Permission denied
init: cannot execve('/system/bin/surfaceflinger'): Permission denied
init: cannot execve('/system/bin/dbus-daemon'): Permission denied 
init: cannot execve('/system/bin/keystore'): Permission denied
```

Like  this  some files in system/bin are getting permissions issue.

I debugged the issue to some stage.
I found that the command:

```
make -j4 PRODUCT-<product_name>-user dist
```

The command above creates a file under out/dist called -target_files.zip. This is the file you need to pass to the sign_target_files_apks script.

When extract this zip file there is SYSTEM folder which contain all system image data.
The files under /bin  didnt have executable permision.
The executable permission is getting missed when copying the files  from the normal android system out folder to the target SYSTEM folder using the command 
ACP in the function product-copy-files  in the MAKEFILE.

Can anyone help how to fix this file permission issue.

Thanks,
Balakrishna

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old but I'm posting this reply in the hope it may help someone else.

You'll see the above errors if the file system is read only. It needs to be read/write. I encountered the problem with a hard drive which Android was mounting as read only because it was corrupt. I was puzzled since the hard drive had always worked in the past and it took me a while to figure out what had gone wrong.

In any case I reformatted the hard drive partitions and reinstalled Android and everything worked again.

Comment: That comment saved me some time, thank you.

On top of that, any custom modifications done to `/system` partition could result in `init` refusing to launch anything.